# changing bash variable names in loop

Tags: bash

I'd like to change the variable used within a bash loop. I'd like the first iteration to echo "/path/to/lol/hello_foo" and the second "/path/to/lol/hello_bar".

But instead, this is printed:

```
/path/to/lol/fname_one
/path/to/lol/fname_two
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

path_data='/path/to/lol'
fname_one='hello_foo'
fname_two='hello_bar'

for count in one two
do
    echo $path_data/fname_$count
done
```

Comment: shouldn't you for loop say : for count in fname_one fname_two do echo $path_data/$count done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indirect variable expansion to do this:

```
...
fname_var=fname_$count
echo "$path_data/${!fname_var}"    # Quoting variable references is a good idea
...
```

But it's generally better to use arrays for things like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

path_data='/path/to/lol'
declare -a fname    # Make fname an array, rather than a plain variable
fname[1]='hello_foo'
fname[2]='hello_bar'

for count in 1 2
do
    echo "$path_data/${fname[count]}"
done
```

If you need text (not numeric) indexes you can use an associative array (bash v4 only):

```
#!/bin/bash

path_data='/path/to/lol'
declare -A fname    # Capital -A makes an associaltive array
fname[one]='hello_foo'
fname[two]='hello_bar'

for count in one two
do
    echo "$path_data/${fname[$count]}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

See ["How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

Your script would look something like this,

```
 #!/bin/bash   

 path_data='/path/to/lol'
 fname_one='hello_foo'
 fname_two='hello_bar'

 for count in one two
 do
   _tmpf="fname_$count"
   echo "$path_data/${!_tmpf}" 
 done
```

Result:

```
~]# ./test.sh 
/path/to/lol/hello_foo
/path/to/lol/hello_bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `eval` (which is probably outdated compared to some of the other answers)

```
#!/bin/bash

path_data='/path/to/lol'
fname_one='hello_foo'
fname_two='hello_bar'

for count in one two
do
    varname=fname_$count
    eval "varval=$"$varname
    echo $path_data/$varval
done
```

As noted by others an array is probably a better solution.